# setting bundler behind proxy

Tags: proxy, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use bundler in my Rails application. But I can't get it working as I'm behind a proxy and I'm not sure how to configure bundler with proxy.

My $http_proxy variable is also set.

I'm using:

Rails - 3.0.0
Bundler - 1.0.7
Linux

And I have red that adding http_proxy to .gemrc file. But I couldn't locate that file in my Linux box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi you need to create the `.gemrc` file. To set the http proxy for RubyGems put the following in `~/.gemrc`

```
---
http_proxy: PROXY_URL
```

Replace PROXY_URL with whatever you currently have in the `http_proxy` environment variable you mentioned.

Comment: No, it should be in your user's home directory. But that's just for RubyGems. Bundler somehow ignores it, so it's moot point. Bundler is a train wreck.

Comment: Might also try using /etc/gemrc for system-wide setting

Comment: I found in the above example for setting the proxy in the `.gemrc` file I had to use `http_proxy` (note the underscore).

Answer (score -2):

I added http_proxy: PROXY_URL (note underscore) into .gemrc which worked for me thanks to David Padbury (comments above).

```
---
http_proxy: PROXY_URL
```